# Package a JavaFX Application as a Native Executable WITH resources

Tags: java, javafx, jpackage

Based on [**this article**](https://inside.java/2023/11/14/package-javafx-native-exec/), and with a default JavaFX tree from IntelliJ Idea (see below), how do I add all resources to commands so that they can be used natively (with getClass().getResource("/style/style.css") or some other way)?

```
src
|_ main
   |_ java
      |_ helloworld
         |_ HelloWordlFX
      |_ module-info.java
   |_ resources
      |_ fonts
         |_ openssans
            |_ opensansregular.ttf
      |_ pictures
         |_ icon.ico
      |_ style
         |_ styles.css
      |_ fxml
         |_ sample.fxml
...
```

Sincerely,

I'm wondering if I should transform the resource folder into a jar, and load it as a module, if there is a specific command to include it in my module, or if the solution lies in using JPackage.
I tried `--resource-dir src/main/resources` with jpackage but to no avail.

Comment: `--rsource-dir` is not for the kind of resources you're talking about; ignore that option for now, as it's for more advanced use cases. Just package the compiled code and resources in a JAR file, then point `jpackage` at said JAR file via `--module-path` (also include the JavaFX on the path, either the JMOD files or the JAR files if you got them from Maven Central). You can use `--module` to tell `jpackage` the main module/main class name.

Comment: could it be related to [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-197469) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the article, @slaw's answer, respecting the tree structure chosen in my question, and for a Microsoft Installer (msi) file:

1.Maven lifecycle > package

2.jpackage to msi :

```
jpackage 
 --dest output 
 --name ShiftingCircle 
 --type msi 
 --module-path "%PATH_TO_FX_JMODS%;target/<NAME>.jar" 
 --add-modules helloworldfx 
 --module helloworldfx/helloworld.HelloWorldFX 
 --win-shortcut --win-menu 
 --java-options -Xmx2048m
```

Answer (score 1):

The `--resource-dir` option is not for the kind of resources you're talking about. You can ignore this option for now; it's for more advanced use cases. The files under `src/main/resources` are meant to be embedded on the class-path/module-path. Typically, this means they should be packaged in a JAR file along with the class files of the project. This setup will continue to "just work" after adding your module to a custom run-time image.

Assuming you want to use `jpackage` manually, then based on your directory structure, the following sequence of (minimal) commands should work for you on Windows using PowerShell (Core 7.4.0):

```bash
$sources = Get-ChildItem src/main/java -r -i *.java | Resolve-Path -Relative
javac -sourcepath src/main/java -p "$env:path_to_fx_jmods" -d out/classes $sources
jar -cf out/app.jar -C out/classes .
jar -uf out/app.jar -C src/main/resources .
jpackage -t app-image -p "$env:path_to_fx_jmods;out/app.jar" -m <module> -d out/app-image
```

<sup>**Note:** All commands should be executed from the parent directory of `src`.</sup>

Where `<module>` is replaced by the main module name and main class name. For example, if your main module's name is `app` and your main class's name is `helloworld.HelloWorldFX`, then you would replace `<module>` with `app/helloworld.HelloWorldFX`. If you set the main class attribute of the JAR file, then you can omit the class name (and the forward slash) and just specify the module name.

This also assumes you have an environment variable `PATH_TO_FX_JOMDS` and that it points to where the JavaFX JMOD files are located. I made this assumption because [one of your comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77591164/package-a-javafx-application-as-a-native-executable-with-resources#comment136791155_77592249) suggests this environment variable exists. If this assumption is incorrect, then replace `$env:path_to_fx_jmods` with the correct value. Note it's paramount the appropriate native code of JavaFX is included in the application image. That means using the JAR files from Maven Central, as they embed the native code, or the JMOD files (the cleaner option when viable).

All that said, I recommend you use a build tool such as Maven or Gradle. It will make this all easier in the long run. See [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) for details on setting up a JavaFX project with Maven or Gradle. Note that build tools are something you use in addition to an IDE (and the IDE should delegate most, if not all, build tasks to the build tool). Both Maven and Gradle have plugins that can work with `jpackage`.

Comment: thanks Slaw, you create the .jar of the compiled files, and you add the .jar of the resources. Do you know if there is another way to do this without using .jar?

The Maven pom.xml used is the one generated by default for a JavaFX project with IntelliJ Idea; and to do the equivalent of these commands, it looks like IntelliJ Idea configuration.

Comment: If you're using Maven, then you can modify the POM file and add a goal to execute jpackage. There are at least two plugins out there, [com.github.akman:jpackage-maven-plugin](https://github.com/Akman/jpackage-maven-plugin) and [org.panteleyev:jpackage-maven-plugin](https://github.com/petr-panteleyev/jpackage-maven-plugin), that can help with this. Or you could probably use the [exec-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

Comment: Note you don't have to compile your code or create the JAR "manually". You can just have Maven do it for you: `mvn compile jar:jar`. The built JAR file (which will be in the `target` directory by default) will include both the compiled code and the resources.

Comment: Ok [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77596207/23027727), and I've made an exec Maven goal for jpackage command. Thanks Slaw

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "jpackage". It is the official tool for packaging Java applications.

It will fit all your needs, it is easy to use, it is complete documented and it comes preinstalled with the JDK.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html

https://www.baeldung.com/java14-jpackage

Comment: Thanks David,
I had seen a lot of articles (including Baeldung), and courses on modules, but rereading the documentation I don't understand when or how to add the resources folder.
According to the documentation --resource-dir path is used to override jpackage resources, so resources is already included.
I understand that the resources folder must be in my module, therefore at the level of this command and/or the module-info file, rather than with JPackage?
dir /s /b *.java > sources.txt & javac --module-path %PATH_TO_FX_JMODS% -d mods/helloworldfx @sources.txt -> Am I on the wrong track?

Comment: Please take a look at @Slaw 's answer. He described it very well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it manually you can make a folder that contains the following elements

- bin : the compiled code of your app
- lib : dependencies (preferably as jar files)
- res : resources
- rt : java runtime (the version must be compatible with your compiled code)

The structure of the files is up to you and it might look something like this

```
└───build_folder
    ├───bin
    ├───lib
    ├───res
    └───rt
```

After that you can check if the setup is working by launching the compiled code using the copied jre, you can open a cmd inside the build folder and type this command

`"rt/bin/java" -cp "bin;res;lib/*" MainClass`

If it works you can make a simple bat file with only the command above in it, Running the bat file will launch the code in bin/ using the jre in rt/ while taking res and lib into the classpath

You can already zip the deploy folder and deploy it into another computer, and it should still work simply by extracting the folder and running the bat.

If you want a more native integration with Windows you can convert the bat into an Exe (there are tools for that online and I can't recommend any).

You can also package the deploy folder into a native installer, see [InnoSetup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) or [NSIS](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page), a native installer would offer options like shortcuts and file type associations.

Also starting from java 11 you can make use of [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jlink.html) and [jdeps](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jdeps.html), which are command line tools that allow you to analyse the dependencies of your project and generate a minimal java runtime getting rid of unneeded modules.

### Note :

every step starting from the creation of the bat file is specific to windows, targeting other operating systems would require a little effort, while the [jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html) tool already does this

> The jpackage tool will take as input a Java application and a Java run-time image, and produce a Java application image that includes all the necessary dependencies. It will be able to produce a native package in a platform-specific format, such as an exe on Windows or a dmg on macOS.

Answer (score -1):

Look into [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

Package your app as a `.jar` file and then use Launch4j to convert it into an `.exe` file.

Comment: Thanks, I have used Launch4J before, but I don't understand how to include the resources in the tools that are presented in this article

Comment: Please do not use launch4j. It is buggy and it does not work half as good as jpackage.